# MySQL Import Access Denied

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I'm trying to import data into a mysql table, but first I would like it to delete all the data inside of the table, and then import the data from a .txt. file.. I am trying to use this as oppose to a REPLACE into statement, which is fine, but I am loading unnecessary information on the php end anyways.

Here is my current syntax:

```
/usr/bin/mysqlimport --host=hostname -u root -password --local --verbose -C  --delete slip  /workplace/gwwallen/ETLdump/test_count.txt
```

And the Error I am getting is:

/usr/bin/mysqlimport --host=hostname -u root -password --local --verbose -C  --delete slip  /workplace/gwwallen/ETLdump/test_count.txt

Enter password: 
Connecting to hostname
/usr/bin/mysqlimport: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'hostname' (using password: YES)

Comment: Is your database located at "hostname"? Somehow I doubt it...

Comment: No it is not. We'll just call it localhost. Didn't feel like including the true hostname.

Comment: Well, you probably typed in the password wrong, or root access isn't allowed from outside.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten this far now.. /usr/bin/mysqlimport --host=localhost -u root -p --local --verbose -C  --delete test /workplace/gwwallen/ETLdump/test_count_portal.txt But, it prompts me for the PW everytime. Any way to have it use a pw I provide?

Comment: Use `-pPASSWORD`(no space between "-p" and your password)

Comment: Great!!! You have done it, but when I did REPLACE into ignore 1 lines, it skipped my columns, currently it is inserting my column names into the db as well. How would you ignore 1 lines. It an import? Thank you so much!

Comment: [`--ignore-lines=1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_ignore-lines)?

Comment: Nailed it! All yours answers worked, I would mark as correct answer. But, in the comments. Thank you again.